# Can I infer the availability of sessionStorage from testing localStorage?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, session-storage

If i were to test for `localStorage` in the users browser with JavaScript, e.g.

```
var hasStorage = (function() {
    try {
        localStorage.setItem(mod, mod);
        localStorage.removeItem(mod);
        return true;
    } catch (exception) {
        return false;
    }
}());

if (hasStorage) {
    // store things in places
}
```

*(from: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/localstorage-pattern)*

Can I infer (without explicit checks) that if `hasStorage === true`, then `sessionStorage` is also available, or is it possible to have one disabled with the other enabled?

Comment: `localStorage` can be disabled at chromium. There is no option to disable `sessionStorage`. If any, the inference is that if `localStorage` is disabled, `sessionStorage` will also be disabled. This can be verified at chromium by launching with `chromium-browser --disable-local-storage` flag then trying to set `sessionStorage`

Comment: @blex at the same compatibility table firefox has an opposite support order. While it is possible to assume that in normal operation both are present, there is no specs to warrant such assumption. So, I'd say that to be on the safe side, its good to treat those as separate entities.

Comment: Interestingly, launched chromium with `--disable-local-storage` flag set, `sessionStorage` was still defined, trying to set `localStorage` logged `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setItem' of null`

Answer (score 3):

`localStorage` does not appear to be related to `sessionStorage` at chromium. It is possible to launch chromium with `--disable-local-storage` flag which logs error when trying to set `localStorage`

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setItem' of null
```

though there does not appear to be an official flag to disable `sessionStorage` at chromium [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/). Note, chrome is built using chromium source code.

Comment: That is interesting. I may be misreading, but wouldn't your research also suggest that if `localStorage` **is** available (i.e. not flagged/disabled as you have shown) then `sessionStorage` would also be available as it can't (as far as can be seen from the specs linked) be disabled, so the test would not need re-running for both?

Comment: `sessionStorage` can be disabled http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882647/can-user-disable-html5-sessionstorage . Suggest checking each.