# Client storage for multipage webform

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, webforms

I have a webform over 11 pages, each containing several questions answered as radio buttons. I need to move to/from each page and save as i go along before submitting to local storage. This is intended as an offline application. Can i save the data from each page to the next and then save it all to localStorage?
Thanks

Comment: Can you just use different DIVs, and when moving on to the next section of the process, hide the current div and show the div with the next set of questions? Then you could submit all of the answers at the same time.

Comment: sounds like a good solution. So i have given all my DIVs an ID and now i need to add something like input type="button" value="Show" onclick="$('#').show()  ??

Comment: What about session variable ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make a SPA so you have 11 views and then you could use the same localstorage and go saving along.

Answer (score 0):

**Use any jQuery form wizard.**
You can use one mentioned below:
http://jquery-plugins.net/steps-jquery-wizard-plugin-with-html5-support

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `sessionStorage` object.

This example is right out of the spec:

*For example, a page could have a checkbox that the user ticks to indicate that he wants insurance:*

```
<label>
 <input type="checkbox" onchange="sessionStorage.insurance = checked ? 'true' : ''">
  I want insurance on this trip.
</label>
```

*A later page could then check, from script, whether the user had checked the checkbox or not:*

```
if (sessionStorage.insurance) { ... }
```

*If the user had multiple windows opened on the site, each one would have its own individual copy of the session storage object.*

http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/

---

Also, there is an excellent discussion on the topic over here: [what is the difference between localStorage, sessionStorage, session and cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867599/what-is-the-difference-between-localstorage-sessionstorage-session-and-cookie)

Comment: So from my understanding i will use sessionStorage to send the data page to page, and then finally localStorage for saving it longer term? The plan is to save until internet becomes available for upload.

Comment: you could also just use localStorage from start to finish if you want.