# Retain changed value of a link when clicked after hitting refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you retain the changed name of a link after a reload or refresh of that page?

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $(this).text("Hello");
});
```

At the moment, if I hit refresh, the link's name will be back to original. In this case, I want to retain the value hello.

Help please.

Comment: you can pass name in url and get back when page relod . or use jquery cookie plugin

Comment: thanks . happy to help you . if my answer help you and solve your problem please accept answer and vote :)

Comment: Can you please check answer and update status??

Answer (score -1):

. you can use jquery [cookie pluing](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)  or you can use [local storage plugin](http://www.jstorage.info/)  . for better understand difference  between local storage and cookie you can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867599/what-is-the-difference-between-localstorage-sessionstorage-session-and-cookie)

```
$("a").click(function(){
  $(this).text("Hello");
  $.cookie('text', "Hello");
});
```

/// code to get value when page load

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   if($.cookie('text')){
     $("element").text($.cookie('text'));
   }
 })
```

Comment: Would trying to do it this way automatically notify the user that there will be problems if they have cookies disabled?

Comment: I did not ask if cookies must be enabled in the browser.  What I asked you was: Would the user automatically be notified that there will be problems if they have cookies disabled?

Comment: yes its default browser feature ..  i also update my answer to use local storage plugin

Comment: You should add an explanation to your answer which shows the difference in utilizing cookie pluing vs local storage.

Comment: @jumbo_burger  .  thanks . happy to help you . if my answer help you and solve your problem please accept answer and vote :)

Comment: @Unipartisandev i have added link which is explain difference. thanks

Comment: The link doesn't explain how to utilize them differently.  What about the code?  That is more what I meant.  Is the jQuery the same for both?