# jQuery change theme on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have problem with themes changing. 
When I click button theme is changing but when I refresh page everything going back to default theme (a). How to set the theme permanently?

main.js

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', function () {
      $('#changeTheme').click(function () {
        $('*[data-role="page"]').attr('data-theme', 'c').removeClass("ui-btn-up-a ui-page-theme-a").addClass("ui-btn-up-b ui-page-theme-c").trigger('create');
      });
    });
```

button in index.html

```
<button id="changeTheme"> Change theme </button>
```

Comment: You would need to maintain a session. See **[sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)** or `localStorage`

Comment: Have your pick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867599/what-is-the-difference-between-localstorage-sessionstorage-session-and-cookie