# Refresh page call back the selected checkboxes Kendo in treeview

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, checkbox

Here, I supposed to click the checkboxes then I send the data into database using submit button (AJAX). After click on submit button, it will be refresh the page but all the selected checkboxes gone. How I do to keep the selected checkboxes after refresh the page? Any idea or guide to do it?

> AJAX

```
//AJAX call for button
    $("#primaryTextButton").kendoButton();
    var button = $("#primaryTextButton").data("kendoButton");
    button.bind("click", function(e) {

    var test = $("#dropdown").val()

    $.ajax({
        url: "../DesignationProgramTemplate/getTemplate.php",
        type: "post",
            data: {'id':test,'progid':array},
                success: function () {
                // you will get response from your php page (what you echo or print)                 
                    kendo.alert('Success'); // alert notification
                    //refresh
                    //location.reload("http://hq-global.winx.ehors.com:9280/ehors/HumanResource/EmployeeManagement/DesignationProgramTemplate/template.php");
                },
        });
    });
```

> PHP for getTemplate

```
$employeeID = $_SESSION['employeeID'];
$propertyID = $_SESSION['propertyID'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$progid = $_POST['progid'];

for($x=0; $x< sizeof($progid); $x++ )
{
    $array = array();   

$positionTemplateID = $ehorsObj->EHORS_PK("tblHrsPositionProgramTemplate"); 
$sqlAdd = "INSERT INTO tblHrsPositionProgramTemplate 
            SET positionTemplateID = '" . $positionTemplateID . "',
            programID = '" . $progid[$x] . "',
            hrsPositionID  = '" . $id . "',
            propertyID   = '" . $propertyID . "',
            employeeID  = '" . $employeeID . "',
            dateTimeEmployee = NOW() ";     

$ehorsObj->ExecuteData($sqlAdd, $ehorsObj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS);

$positionTemplateIDLog = $ehorsObj->EHORS_PK("tblHrsPositionProgramTemplateLog");   
$sqlAddLog = "INSERT INTO tblHrsPositionProgramTemplateLog 
            SET positionTemplateIDLog = '" . $positionTemplateIDLog . "',
            positionTemplateID = '" . $positionTemplateID . "',
            programID = '" . $progid[$x] . "',
            hrsPositionID  = '" . $id . "',
            propertyID   = '" . $propertyID . "',
            employeeID  = '" . $employeeID . "',
            dateTimeEmployee = NOW() ";     

$ehorsObj->ExecuteData($sqlAddLog, $ehorsObj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS);
}
```

> Function for checkboxes

```
function checkedNodeIds(nodes, checkedNodes) {
  for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    if (nodes[i].checked) {
      //checkedNodes.push(nodes[i].moduleID);
     // checkedNodes.push(nodes[i].groupID);
      checkedNodes.push(nodes[i].id);
    }

    if (nodes[i].hasChildren) {
      checkedNodeIds(nodes[i].children.view(), checkedNodes);
    }
  }

}
```

> Checkboxes check

```
function toggleCheckAll() {
        var checkButtonValue = $("#chbAll").val();

        if(checkButtonValue == "Uncheck"){
          $("#AccountingTree .k-checkbox-wrapper input").prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
          $("#AdminSystemTree .k-checkbox-wrapper input").prop("checked", true).trigger("change");

          $("#chbAll").val("Check");
        } else {
          $("#AccountingTree .k-checkbox-wrapper input").prop("checked", false).trigger("change");
          $("#AdminSystemTree .k-checkbox-wrapper input").prop("checked", false).trigger("change");

          $("#chbAll").val("Uncheck");

        }
```

}

> HTML

```
<div class="selectAll">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chbAll" value="Uncheck" class="k-checkbox" onchange="toggleCheckAll()" />

  <label class="k-checkbox-label" for="chbAll">Select All</label>
```

Anyone have the idea about it?

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20rJf.png)

Comment: An idea its link a session with all selected

Comment: Can you show some example?

Comment: For example, when you send, to data base you are using PHP, in this case you can save the ``nodes[i].id`` in a session, for example if you are iterating about checked boxes, if you find, add to a session, for example: ``SESSION['somesession'] .= nodes[i].id .';'``

Comment: Do i need to create new session?

Comment: Only 1 time for link all sessions, separated for example by ``';'``. nodeid1;nodeid2...

Comment: I understand what you mean but I can't see it clearly. Can you modified into my PHP above?

Comment: What do you mean by prepared statement? @Dharman

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: I'm still not clearly about it for the session.

Comment: Have you FTP server where can i check it ?

Comment: Because I'm try to see some solution are using cookies, localStorage etc .But I don't know how to apply it into my code.

Comment: Noted, thank you @Dharman

Comment: OK, i will do it, idk how much time i will be this, i will back with 1 PHP, example.

Comment: Okay, I will wait to see the example. Thank you.

Comment: I made without session, more simple

Comment: But here, my checkboxes not in html. I will put above the code for checkboxes which using treeview kendo that have checkboxes.

Comment: But, you for see the checkboxes like on the picture, are in html no ? Can you inspect element and add the HTML output ?

Comment: I have added the html for checkboxes at above.

Comment: The function ``toggleCheckAll()`` its JavaScript ? looks like to jquery idk

Comment: Yes, it is function for to checkboxes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44589201/save-checkbox-value-with-javascript-the-easy-way

Comment: This probably can make a solution to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961069/getting-value-get-or-post-variable-using-javascript But only from GET method. You can parse these values.

Comment: I will try make it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your solution not helped me. I'm still stuck here.

Comment: This is an example, you need implement on your script, works 100%

Comment: I'm using post , is it still working?

Comment: With POST no. But another trick is using document.cookie https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Alright, thank you!. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

With this you can save the checked boxes, remember its with `GET` method.

```
<html>

<body>

<form method="get" action="">

    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle3" value="Boat"> I have a boat<br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>

</body>

    <script>

        var a = window.location.search.substr(1).split('&');
        console.log(a);
        function test(value, index){ a[index] = value.split("="); }
        function test2(value, index){ console.log(document.getElementsByName(value[0])); document.getElementsByName(value[0])[0].checked = true; }
        a.forEach(test);
        a.forEach(test2);

    </script>

</html>
```