# When is necesary use ngCookies over localStorage or localSession?

Tags: angularjs

How it says in the question, could some one can explain when is necesary the use **ngCookies** over **localStorage** or **localSession** in some uses cases, why asking, i recently have a project which have the priority to track some conditions, and store about its desitions, so i actually use localStorage to save, lets say configuration preferences, but, instead i see examples with cookies so, the question is about in which cases is better one over the others.

Comment: ngCookies is just a wrapper for reading/writing browser cookies, so this might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies

Comment: my question isnt about what is ngcookies is more to know... in which cases its better to use ng-cookies over the others.

Comment: That's what the link answers for you. If you're reading/writing from a sever you'd probably want ngCookies. If you're just reading/writing in the client you'd probably want the localStorage/Session option

Comment: thx dude it helps to understand how they work, and how can i now decide if needs cookie or webstorage.

Comment: actually i found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960037/localstorage-vs-sessionstorage-vs-cookies lol..... when i research never came to mind to put the question like this. lol.