# Storing Data into an Array Using vm in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am storing data into an array but when I refresh the page, the data disappears on my page.

This is my JS code:

```
function VideoController () {
  var vm = this;

  vm.videos = [];

  vm.addVideoUrl = function(text) {
  vm.videos.push(angular.copy(text)); //HOW I AM TRYING TO SAVE DATA INTO MY ARRAY, VIDEOS
}

}
```

Comment: we need more information. however it seems the controller is attached to your view -> it loads every time you refresh the page and sets vm.videos to []

Answer (score 3):

Every time you refresh a new instance of the controller is created. Therefor the array is reinitialized to be empty.

You can use the browser's local storage for storing and getting your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$cookies` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) to temporarily save data. This is preferable over local storage because it has an expiry time by default.

Comment: Remember that cookies size is limited, try not to store too much data there. User can have also cookies disabled on his browser - just a thing to remember.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**localstorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [**sessionstorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), see [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) the diferences.

The following example demonstrates how to use it for your case

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var saveVideosToStorage = function(){
      localStorage.setItem('videos', angular.toJson($scope.videos));
    } 

    var init = function() {
      //load video array from localstorage/sessionStorage
      var videos = angular.fromJson(localStorage.getItem('videos')); 
      if (!(videos instanceof Array)) {
          //videos has been corrupted
          $scope.videos = [];
          saveVideosToStorage();
      }

      $scope.videos = videos;
    }

    var addVideoUrl = function(text) {
      $scope.videos.push(angular.copy(text)); //HOW I AM TRYING TO SAVE DATA INTO MY ARRAY, VIDEOS
      saveVideosToStorage();
    }

    $scope.addVideoUrl = addVideoUrl;
    init();
  }]);
```

and the markup

```
<div ng-repeat="video in videos track by $index">{{video}}</div>
    <input ng-model="videoUrl" type="text"/>
    <input type="button" ng-click="addVideoUrl(videoUrl);">
```

And here is the [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/DaXqtMT98phEHShmeub7?p=preview)

**NOTE:**

I used `%scope` instead of the `var vm = this`

I have found an explanation about localStorage, sessionStorage and cookies that is easy to understand see it [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867599/what-is-the-difference-between-localstorage-sessionstorage-session-and-cookies).