# Detect and store clicked linked inside a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My idea is this: a div contains a dynamic number (from 1 to N) of links.
When I click any link, all redirect  to *"nextpage.php"*. I would like to store the clicked link and then recover his name.

```
<div class="myclass">
    <a href="nextpage.php" name="name1">Value 1</a>
    <a href="nextpage.php" name="name2">Value 2</a>
    <a href="nextpage.php" name="name3">Value 3</a>
    .
    .
    .
    < href="nextpage.php" name="valueN">Value N</a>
</div>
```

For example, if i click on *Value3* , I will be redirected to nextpage.php and I will need recover *Value3*. 
I should use javascript to implement this?
Thank for you help.

Comment: Use `sessionStorage`...`$(this).attr('name')` or if you want to use this `name` in the next page then use `queryString argument(?name=name3)`

Comment: Why you can't try it with query string like as nextpage.php?name=value2

Comment: POST or GET method. Or session variable.

Comment: SessionStorage, cookies, localStorage... Here a good guide too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867599/what-is-the-difference-between-localstorage-sessionstorage-session-and-cookies

Comment: thanks for your comment! I have used GET variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need any javascript. Use GET variables.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="myclass">
<a href="nextpage.php?name=value1" name="name1">Value 1</a>
<a href="nextpage.php?name=value2" name="name2">Value 2</a>
<a href="nextpage.php?name=value3" name="name3">Value 3</a>
.
.
.
<a href="nextpage.php?name=valueN" name="valueN">Value N</a>
</div>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['name']){
    $name = $_GET['name'];
}else{
    $name = 'Default value';
}
```