# Token based Authentication with Angular

Tags: angularjs, local-storage, token, http-token-authentication, angular-cookies

I want to authenticate users through api, when username and password is right it returns a token and store on local storage using ngStorage but I read some articles that it's not secure saving token on localStorage, and they made reference to storing it to cookies Http. How can I store the token on cookies Http and is it secure or is there a better way of handling token authentication

```
$scope.loginUser = function(){
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'ourdomain.com/api/token',
      headers: 
      {
          'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      data: 
      'UserName=' + $scope.username + 
      '&Password=' + $scope.password 
      }).success(function(data, status) {
               $localStorage.token = data;
               console.log(data);
      })
      .error(function(data, status) {
          console.log("Error");
      });
}
```

Comment: You could start with looking into angular-cookies: https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies

Answer (score 2):

for cookie the user can disable cookie.

this link can explain you  Token based vs. Cookie based

https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/

and this for the difference between localStorage, sessionStorage, session and cookies :
[What is the difference between localStorage, sessionStorage, session and cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867599/what-is-the-difference-between-localstorage-sessionstorage-session-and-cookies)

Answer (score 1):

I warmly suggest you to use stallizer: https://github.com/sahat/satellizer

**Login with Email and Password**

> Client: Enter your email and password into the login form.
>
> Client: On form submit call $auth.login() with email and password.
>
> Client: Send a POST request to /auth/login.
>       Server: Check if email exists, if not - return 401.
>
> Server: Check if password is correct, if not - return 401.
>
> Server: Create a JSON Web Token and send it back to the client.
>
> Client: Parse the token and save it to Local Storage for subsequent use after page reload.

```
var user = {
  email: $scope.email,
  password: $scope.password
};

$auth.login(user)
  .then(function(response) {
    // Redirect user here after a successful log in.
  })
  .catch(function(response) {
    // Handle errors here, such as displaying a notification
    // for invalid email and/or password.
  });


// Controller
$scope.isAuthenticated = function() {
  return $auth.isAuthenticated();
};

<!-- Template -->
<ul ng-if="!isAuthenticated()">
  <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
  <li><a href="/signup">Sign up</a></li>
</ul>
<ul ng-if="isAuthenticated()">
  <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can I use this with my api? I can see clientID, what is clientID? Also I think it uses other social network login but not with my own Login API

Comment: for example to respond to POST request to /auth/login. instead of ourdomain.com/api/token

Comment: what of the clientID, what is it about?

Comment: if you want to use an external auth provider, like Facebook, but that is not your case

Comment: I read about auth0, it seems to be an online user management system, that's not what i want

Comment: https://github.com/sahat/satellizer#-login-with-email-and-password check this section, I'm just telling you not to reinvent the wheel... I'm not saying it is all automagic

Comment: my problem is that how can i adapt my api to it? do you have any example you can show

Comment: dude you are not reading, I wrote it in the 2nd comment, you need to adapt the API to respond to the /auth/login POST and return the JWT Token.

Comment: you mean my post request will go to ourdomain.com/auth/login

Comment: exactly! and then serverside you have to return a valid JWT Token

Comment: check the server examples: https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/tree/master/examples/server, then it will work :)