# Set cookie from Laravel and get null from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5.4

Whenever I set a cookie from Laravel like this :

```
return redirect($this->redirectTo)->withCookie(cookie('token', auth()->user()->api_token, 60)); // set cookie for 60 minutes
```

And I want to get that cookie from Javascript like this:

```
var token = localStorage.getItem('token');
console.log(token);
```

But it always return `null`

I'm pretty sure cookie is already set on browser and not null using cookie manager add-ones.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you are confused between cookie and localStorage. Access the cookie using `console.log(document.cookie);` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867599/what-is-the-difference-between-localstorage-sessionstorage-session-and-cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that Laravel cookies stored in `localStorage` ?

To get cookies using JavaScript you can use [document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

---

To get a cookie by name you can use this code:

```js
function getCookie(name) {
  var value = "; " + document.cookie;
  var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
  if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}

var token = getCookie('token');

console.log(token);
```

Code copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15724300/6568620)

Comment: The output is `undefined`

Comment: What is the output of this code `console.log(document.cookie);` ?

Comment: It's working now. The problem was for because this cookie was set as `httponly`. I set `httponly` to false in laravel and it worked like a charm. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Cookie::queue($name, $value, $minutes);
This will queue the cookie to use it later and later it will be added with the response when response is ready to be sent. You may check the documentation on Laravel website.
Update (Retrieving A Cookie Value):$value = Cookie::get('name');