# What is the best practice to handle badge in a header in asp.net core?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core-2.0, badge

So I'm implementing a small badge in my header indicating how many items the user has in his cart..

This is how I've thought of doing it: Set the badge value on user log in and then just increment/decrement it when the user adds/removes from his cart.

I tried setting the value in jquery on my index page like this:

```
function loadCartBadgeVal(id) {
$.getJSON(`/Cart/GetCartCount?customerId=${id}`,
    function (data) {
        $("#cart-badge").text('' + data);
    }); 
}
```

This works but when I redirect to another page my badge value resets to 0 .. my badge is implemented in a partial view like this:

```
<span class="badge badge-info" id="cart-badge"></span>
```

Comment: are you calling the `loadCartBadgeVal` on the page where you redirect to , you need to load the value on every page.

Comment: Does this mean I need to do a database call every single time? Is there no better way to do that?

Comment: so u better save it in the session, cookies, localstorage etc

Comment: if you are using this count to show only the items in the cart you do not need to use the databases, if I would have to do it via javascript I would use `localStorage` to hold the values temporarily until checked out. that way i just need to call the session variable on every page and nothing else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` to save the cart items count and show it anywhere on your site/app.

The following snippet accesses the current domain's local Storage object and adds a data item to it using `Storage.setItem()`.

```
localStorage.setItem('cartCount', 1);
```

The syntax for reading the localStorage item is as follows:

```
var count= localStorage.getItem("cartCount");
```

The syntax for removing the localStorage item is as follows:

```
localStorage.removeItem("cartCount");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Muhammad. This might be a totally new question but why localStorage over a Sessionvariable?

Comment: Well, `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` both extend `Storage` . There is no difference between them except for the intended "non-persistence" of `sessionStorage`. That is, the data stored in `localStorage` persists until explicitly deleted. Changes made are saved and available for all current and future visits to the site. see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867599/what-is-the-difference-between-localstorage-sessionstorage-session-and-cookies) @J.Kirk.