# Keep table sort result after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-storage, tablesort

I'm using the table sorter from w3.js(https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp).
Also, I have used setTimeout to refresh page per minute for updating data.
I want to keep the sorting result after refreshing page.
I know there's a method is using sessionStorage, but don't know how to use it.
Can anybody give me some tips?

Comment: Are you OK to call sortTable() when page/table load?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I'm using the second example. It gives each columns different number. How should I do?

Comment: I added a snippet below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an updated snippet of the example in [SortTable](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sort_table_desc). We use the browser cookies to restore the last sort information, which are mainly the sorting column and direction. There is another example in W3school, from which I got the cookie handling ([Cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_cookie_username)). The snippet below will not work here in the website because of the cross origin policy. Certainly, it also requires some refactoring, but it is a start.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sort a HTML Table Alphabetically</title>
<style>
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th {
    cursor: pointer;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 16px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="checkCookie();">

<p><strong>Click the headers to sort the table.</strong></p>
<p>The first time you click, the sorting direction is ascending (A to Z).</p>
<p>Click again, and the sorting direction will be descending (Z to A):</p>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
   <!--When a header is clicked, run the sortTable function, with a parameter, 0 for sorting by names, 1 for sorting by country:-->  
    <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Name</th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
function sortTable(n, dir) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  !dir && (dir = "asc"); 
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /*check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount ++;      
    } else {
      /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
  
  setCookie("sortBy", n, 30);
  setCookie("sortByDir", dir);
}


function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var sortBy=getCookie("sortBy");
    if (sortBy != "") {
        sortTable(parseInt(sortBy), getCookie("sortByDir"));
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit:
One more snippet to use sessionStorage instead

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sort a HTML Table Alphabetically</title>
<style>
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th {
    cursor: pointer;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 16px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="checkStrorage();">

<p><strong>Click the headers to sort the table.</strong></p>
<p>The first time you click, the sorting direction is ascending (A to Z).</p>
<p>Click again, and the sorting direction will be descending (Z to A):</p>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
   <!--When a header is clicked, run the sortTable function, with a parameter, 0 for sorting by names, 1 for sorting by country:-->  
    <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Name</th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
function sortTable(n, dir) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  !dir && (dir = "asc"); 
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /*check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount ++;      
    } else {
      /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
  
  sessionStorage.setItem('sortBy', n);
  sessionStorage.setItem('sortByDir', dir);
}

function checkStrorage() {
    var sortBy= sessionStorage.getItem('sortBy');
    if (sortBy !== null) {
        sortTable(parseInt(sortBy), sessionStorage.getItem('sortByDir'));
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying. But is it better to use sessionStorage instead of cookies? Cause when page close, the session will clear the value while cookies won't.

Comment: Added another snippet that uses sessionStorage instead. Deciding which is better can be seen in this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867599/what-is-the-difference-between-localstorage-sessionstorage-session-and-cookies)

Comment: Please let me know how it went. If everything is OK, please close your question by selecting my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! It does work! Btw, I think the getStorage function is not in use when using sessionStorage.