# In Single Page Application which is the best way to maintain user session?

Tags: single-page-application, session-management

I am developing an SPA using MERN technology stack. I want to maintain user session. Which are the best ways use session management and what information we need to store in client side?
1) Session storage 
2) Local Storage 
3) Cookie.

Comment: This post might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867599/what-is-the-difference-between-localstorage-sessionstorage-session-and-cookies/19869560#19869560