# SharePoint Add-in user can change color of web part

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have made a application for SharePoint online and want the users to be able to customize every element like the background color font color etc. I would like to have a color pallet that the user can pick from like this:

[image]

I know SharePoint have its limitations but is this possible to accomplish?
I want it to be under the Edit web part options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [jscolor](http://jscolor.com/) library which allow user select color, while you may need store the value with proper policy so you could use it in future(Or store in a SharePoint list).[localStorage, sessionStorage, session and cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867599/what-is-the-difference-between-localstorage-sessionstorage-session-and-cookies)

Then, set element CSS by [jQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp).

Comment: But how can i get it in the option list of the web part? Currently it looks like this https://i.gyazo.com/86041569c66fc3224a0e82c4585c1773.png And I dont want it to list 100+ colors and neither have hex color input field.

Comment: You have to create a configuration page for your web part as we can't create custom control/logic in OOB property panel.