# Passing Variables from one page to another

Tags: javascript, html, variables

Im trying to pass a value from one page for a product to another page for the cart.

I've tried a few different options but haven't managed to come up with any solution.

I'm new to html and javascript so need a simple solution if thats possible so that I can understand.

Product Page

```
<label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
<div>
   <select class="form-control" id="Selected">
       <option value='1'>1</option>
       <option value='2'>2</option>
       <option value='3'>3</option>
       <option value='4'>4</option>
       <option value='5'>5</option>
   </select>
</div>
<button id='btn' type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Add To Cart</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var value=0;

   function send_selected(){
      var selector = document.getElementById('Selected');
      var value = selector[selector.selectedIndex].value;

      sessionStorage.setItem(value);
   }

   document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',send_selected);
</script>
```

Cart page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var value = sessionStorage.getItem("value");
   document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = value;
</script>

<body>
  <div id="display"></div>
</body>
```

I would need to value from the drop down to be passed to the cart page to work out the value for all the users products selected.

Comment: check here for how to use setItem https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

Answer (score 1):

You need to add two arguments to sessionStorage: key and value. Something like this:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("selectValue", value);
```

Also, as far as I know if you work with local html files opened like `path/cart.html` in the browser, the sessionStorage can't help you; it's scope is limited to the page. If you serve them through localhost, you'll be alright.

Answer (score 0):

If this pages have different url, you can do it with query params: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Answer (score 0):

**By Browser Storage Method :**

As mentioned by @Ferenc, the setItem method of session storage takes two parameters.

```
sessionStorage.setItem("selectedItem","value");
```

or you can use 
sessionStorage["selectedItem"] = "value";

And to retrieve the value anywhere else in the browser you can either use the  `getItem()` method or you can go with the array like value access approach i.e.

```
var value = sessionStorage["selected"];
```

But I would suggest you go with localStorage instead of sessionStorage, Because of it's larger scope than the sessionStorage scope.
You can read [difference b/w session storage and local storage here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19869560/4574765)
Note: You can check for errors in your javascript code(Which now occurs when you call the getItem method with a single parameter ) by looking in the browser console.


**By Query Parameters:** 


Well, this is not a recommended method if you are not using any server-side language. i.e. Java, PHP etc.
In this case, you append the query string in url. i.e.

```
http://www.url.com?value=selected
```

To Read how to access query parameters by using javascript refer to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery-or-how-to-get-query-string-values-in-js/21903119)

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me to add to the 1st HTML file:

```js
where_from = document.getElementById("where_from").value;
sessionStorage.setItem("pass_to_other_form", where_from);
```

and then to the 2nd HTML file:

```js
var from_other = sessionStorage.getItem("pass_to_other_form");
```