# Keep Todo Results after browser refreshing

Tags: javascript

I created a todo app to add  and remove tasks  on the page.
however i would like to keep  todo results  when browser refreshed .
Is that possible to make this  like storing data on db or any storage  to save these results?
any idea  to make this  to save data ??

Now I posted   the complete code hereee! because i cant posted code here before

```js
let menu = document.querySelector(".bs");
let btn1 = document.querySelector(".btn");
let btn2 = document.querySelector(".btn3");
 
 let irp = document.querySelector(".date");
let inp = document.querySelector(".input");
let bsd = document.querySelector(".sss");
let brs  = document.querySelector(".marker");

let addBr = () => {
  btn1.addEventListener("click", addBr);

  let br = document.createElement("DIV");
  let dd  =  document.createElement("H1");
  dd.innerHTML = (inp.value);
  br.className = "red";
  var bn = document.createElement("H1");
  bn.innerHTML = (irp.value);
  


  menu.appendChild(br);
  br.appendChild(dd);
    br.appendChild(bn);

  if(  inp.value == "") {
            br.remove();

  }
  
  else {
       menu.appendChild(br);

  }
  
  
  if(  irp.value == "") {
   dd.innerHTML = "Albenis";

  
  }
  
  else {
       menu.appendChild(br);

  }

  
  let ttt = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  ttt.className = "marker";
  ttt.innerHTML = "Remove";
  br.appendChild(ttt);
  
  // This is the important change. Part of creating the .ttt element
  // is setting up its event listeners!
  ttt.addEventListener('click', () => br.remove());
  
};

btn1.addEventListener("click", addBr);

// Call `addBr` once to add the initial element
addBr();
```

```html
<html>

<body>


<div class="bs">



<input type="text" class="input">
<input type="date" class="date">
<button class="btn">
Add
</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add your minimal code to reproduce it.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [What is the difference between localStorage, sessionStorage, session and cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19869560/3113485)

Comment: i posted code here Nikz

Comment: if localstorage saves  entries it would be nice who tell me  how to   configure localstorage  in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: use localStorage to read the items at page load and write the items when they change, like in the [final version](https://jsfiddle.net/7kodcf9v)

To keep your todo entries, you need to store it in a Database. This can be either a local database in the website like [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Or you need to build a backend which is connected to a Database and send and load the Data from there.

localStorage example:

```js
const items = [{ name: "My Todo" }, { name: "My Todo 2" }];

const setItems = () => {
  localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(items));
};

const getItems = () => {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items"));
};
```

Including your code:

```js
const getItems = () => {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items"));
};

const items = getItems() || [];

const setItems = () => {
  localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(items));
};

let addBr = (item) => {
  let br = document.createElement("DIV");
  let dd  =  document.createElement("H1");
  dd.innerHTML = (item ? item.name : inp.value);
  br.className = "red";
  var bn = document.createElement("H1");
  bn.innerHTML = (item ? item.name : irp.value);

  if (!item) {
    items.push({ name: inp.value });
    setItems();
  }

  menu.appendChild(br);
  br.appendChild(dd);
    br.appendChild(bn);

  if(  inp.value == "") {
            br.remove();

  }

  else {
       menu.appendChild(br);

  }


  if(  irp.value == "") {
   dd.innerHTML = "Albenis";


  }

  else {
       menu.appendChild(br);

  }


  let ttt = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  ttt.className = "marker";
  ttt.innerHTML = "Remove";
  br.appendChild(ttt);

  // This is the important change. Part of creating the .ttt element
  // is setting up its event listeners!
  ttt.addEventListener('click', () => br.remove());
};

for (const item of items) {
  addBr(item);
}

btn1.addEventListener("click", () => addBr());
```

Comment: I just want only keep todo items  when browser refreshing  no any database i know with php is more easier because  items saved on server and database

Comment: You need to keep track of your items in your HTML Element render code.
Your goal is to render a array of items like:

[{ name: "My Todo" }, { name: "My Todo 2" }]

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'addBr' before initialization
 ? how to fix that  ? can you tell me

Comment: you need to declare the `addBr ` function before you call it. I will adjust my answer.

Comment: this method not worked ,i cannot add todos any more , it shows todo with name my todo 1 and my todo 2 !!

Comment: yes because you can empty the array like const items = []; my answer has example data in it.

Get the items using const items = getItems() || []; using my getItems function...

Comment: and how to  write now because my todo doesnt produce any item? after  removing arrays

Comment: change btn1.addEventListener("click", addBr); to btn1.addEventListener("click", () => addBr());

Comment: thanks now this now fixed   but when  i refresh   browser todo not  saved on localstorage still not worked  i remove array and make only  const items = [];  but still dont worked

Comment: yes now you need to save the items with the setItems(); function but before you call setItems(); need to push the new item into the items array.

Comment: still not worked   thank you very much for your helping me  ,still not saved when browser refreshed

Comment: you can look in the console for localStorage entries:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/storage/localstorage

Comment: no  any errors in  if you want i can send you all  the code of editor

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dkepz9av/258/    all the code now i uploaded in  new jsfiddle

Comment: i want to save  created todos in html page when browser refreshing , is this possible?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7kodcf9v/ had a small bug, this is the fully working version