# How to setTimeout will not repeat when reload in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have some data and its processing code as follows:

```
LIST = [{
    "id": "1lqgDs6cZdWBL",
    "timeUpdated": "2020-04-22 12:51:23",
    "status": "CLOSED"
}, {
    "id": "C2Zl9JWfZHSJ",
    "timeUpdated": "2020-04-22 12:51:07",
    "status": "CLOSED"
}, {
    "id": "BHbiVcCaQa2d",
    "timeUpdated": "2020-04-15 14:53:12",
    "status": "CLOSED"
}];


ngOnInit() {
  this.initializeAlertTimer();
}
initializeAlertTimer(data?: any, duration?: any) {
  const DURATION = duration ? 20000 : 1000
  setTimeout(() => {
  }, DURATION)
}

addData() {
  const data = {
     "id": "qHFw59mujN9X",
     "timeCreated": "2020-03-06 12:21:06",
     "status": "NEW",
   }
   this.initializeAlertTimer(data, 20000);
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is when opening the application it will list all the data `LIST` from the console once even it will change a page or reload the page it shouldn't repeat and when clicking on the `addData()` it will add the new data then by `initializeAlertTime()` it will display the newest data.

Comment: you're going to need to set something, either via a cookie, or through `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` in order to indicate whether or not the the page was loaded once before.  Please see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867599/what-is-the-difference-between-localstorage-sessionstorage-session-and-cookies#:~:text=OK%2C%20LocalStorage%20as%20it's%20called,tiny%20data%20storing%20in%20your) for a quick breakdown of the difference.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do the same ex:
1)Using localstorage,
2)sessionstorage
3)service class

***localstorage***

**Save into LocalStorage:**

```
localStorage.setItem('key', value);
```

**For objects with properties:**

```
localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(object));
```

**Get From Local Storage:**

```
localStorage.getItem('key');
```

**For objects:**

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'));
```

**And you can use this part of the code to get remaining time**

```
localStorage.setItem('DURATION',DURATION)
    localStorage.setItem('start',Date.now()) // milliseconds
```

when needed

```
    const elapsed = Date.now() - localStorage.getItem('start');
    const remaining =  localStorage.setItem('DURATION') - elapsed; // divide by 1000 for seconds
```

**Note**:Value will be reserve when reload
2)localStorage Object will save data as string and retrieve as string. You need to Parse desired output if value is object stored as string. e.g. parseInt(localStorage.getItem('key'));

Comment: do you have example?

Answer (score 1):

When you reload the application, all your variables and stack gets reinitialized. So there is no way to track whether the user has visited the firs time of just reloaded the application.

You can store some value in your **database** to keep track or use **localstorage** or **session storage**.

If you want to keep track while changing the screen that could be possible by using the **service** and defining the variable.

When you user visits the page for second time you just check the value of the variable stored in the service.

Comment: do you have sample?