# Best practice, should I wrap getSessionStorage in a try catch

Tags: javascript, try-catch

## Background

I'm using session storage in an application I'm writing. I know that sometimes its not supported in very old browsers. In addition I guess there could be browser settings or extensions that can mess with session storage. As in stop something from being retrieved or saved etc. & crash the app.

## Question

Can these outlying scenarios crash my app? And is it best to wrap a getSessionStorage in a try catch to gracefully fail?

Comment: You are talking like IE7..... seems a bit old to worry about lack of support.

Comment: Good old [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) days :)

Comment: thanks @epascarello, so this is not worth adding I gather. Thank you for the input, its been awhile since i wrote some session storage stuff.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49323105/1048572) lists two cases where a regular (i.e. not modified by an extension etc) storage throws exceptions. Yes, you better catch those.