Restrict cookies in the request header for the APIs
I am developing an application with the following stack
Frontend - Angular
Backend - JAVA Springboot
Both the applications are hosted on the same domain.
When I am logging into my application, the cookies stored in the domain are getting sent to the request header. But, I am not explicitly sending any cookies to header.The browser is sending this cookies to the API. I have tried multiple ways to restrict the cookies from frontend code. But none of the solutions are working.
Is there any way to restrict the cookies being sent in the request header from Angular ?
I have tried multiple ways

Restricting cookies using withCredential: false method in Angular HTTP Interceptor.
Tried to restrict it with the service worker file.


This question is similar to: Is it possible to prevent cookies to be sent in every HTTP request?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

By design, the cookies are added to every request. Whatever you are trying to store, maybe you should not use cookies for that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#data_storage

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867599

while Fetch API would do this with credentials: omit, I believe RXJS/HttpClient/XMLHttpRequest, withCredentials option as false only excludes cookies when cross-origin.  See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials  (So don't set them to begin with...)

Step 1: Import HttpClientModule
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    // other imports
  ],
  // ...
})
export class AppModule {}

Step 2: Configure withCredentials in Your HTTP Requests
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getData() {
    return this.http.get('https://example.com/api/data', {
      withCredentials: false // Disable cookies
    });
  }

  postData(data: any) {
    return this.http.post('https://example.com/api/data', data, {
      withCredentials: false // Disable cookies
    });
  }
}

